# Do you know any free website to check my own sentences in English?

Tags: discussion

After learning a new words in English and I am making a new sentence to remember But I need to know this sentence is correct or not. Do you know any free website or community check like this sentences?

If anybody know any information about that. Can help me?

Thanks.